# create and joining websocket via laravel-echo in react app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, laravel-echo, pusher-js

i am using [laravel-echo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-echo) to create and use websocket in my react-app.
its easy to use laravel-echo in a page. but when need to use in several pages, it make several channel and subscribe several time.
**how to make a single channel and join ones in several pages ? with props or something ...**

i try via props like below but there was some error:

> parent Component:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

const token = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');


const options = {
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '7890165486',
    wsHost: '45.149.78.4',
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    authEndpoint: 'http://xxx.xxx.net/broadcasting/auth',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            Accept: 'application/json'
        }
    }
};

const echo = new Echo(options);

Class ParentComponnet extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    this.EchoJoin();
}

EchoJoin() {
    let ch = echo.join(`chat.${this.props.token}`);
    ch
        .here((user) => {
            console.log('all online use', user);
        })
        .joining((user) => {
            alert(user.id + ' New Join the Channel');
        })
        .leaving((user) => {
            alert(user.id + ' Leave the Channel');
        })
        .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
            console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>', e);
        });
}
<ChildComponent ch={this.echo} />
}
```

> and this is child Component code :

```
    componentDidMount() {
    this.props.ch
        .here((user) => {
            console.log('all online use', user);
        })
        .joining((user) => {
            alert(user.id + ' New Join the Channel');
        })
        .leaving((user) => {
            alert(user.id + ' Leave the Channel');
        })
        .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
            console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>', e);
        });

    }
```

> i got this error
> [image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'here' of undefined]

Comment: ch is undefined. Which means it was never passed down as a prop. Show your code when you call the component that you are using ch and getting an error.

Comment: thank you dear Doug Watkins. i edit the question so it show the code in clean way

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a way you answered your own question. You need a singleton here, so I would initialize the connection in a root container, and then pass down what you need as a prop to each screen you need it in.

Let me know if you need any clarification on that.

EDIT:
Looks like your connection is called ch, so you would just need to pass that down to your children as a prop. Assuming that you have your code in one of your high level root components/containers - such as App.js - you would pass it down like such.

```
<View>
  <SomeChildComponent ch={this.ch} />
</View>
```

EDIT:
You are doing this to render your child component:

`<ChildComponent ch={this.echo} />`

But it should be this:

`<ChildComponent ch={this.ch} />`

Comment: thank you for your response .
i try to do it via props but unsuccessful .
could you please show the way so i implement it?

Comment: i edited the question and added more details to it . could you please help me?